# Nilpotent matrix and similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

If $A$ is a complex matrix of order $n$ and $A$ is nilpotent, that is, there exists a positive integer $s$ such that $A^s=0$. Let's say that $e^A = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!}$. Prove that $e^A$ is similar to $I_n+A$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

Comment: As $A$ is a complex matrix what is the well-known result you can use first ? I mean to which matrix $A$ is similar ?

Comment: We can use that A is similar to its Jordan standard form.Obviously,the diagonal of the standard form is all zero.

Comment: @Piquancy If that's allowed, then it's sufficient to show that this holds in the case that $A$ is a nilpotent Jordan block. The remaining cases can be addressed using direct sums and similarity

Comment: @Maman What exactly do you mean by "here it will be of order 2"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Unfortunately,I couldn't prove the Jordan block.I had already transitioned to that form before.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that this holds in the case that $A$ is a nilpotent Jordan block (of size $n$) with eigenvalue $0$.

Note that it is equivalent to show that $e^A - I$ is similar to $A$, and that that a matrix $B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ is similar to a nilpotent Jordan block (of size $n$) if and only if it is nilpotent with $B^{n-1} \neq 0$. So, let $B = e^A - I$. By considering the series expansion $B = A\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{(k+1)!}$, note that for all exponents $m$, we have
$$
B^m = A^m (I + a_1 A^1 + \cdots + a_{n-1}A^{n-1})
$$
for some coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1} \in \Bbb C$. Conclude therefore that $B^{n-1} = A^{n-1} \neq 0$ and that $B^{n} = 0$. Thus, $B$ must be similar to a Jordan block of size $n$, which is to say that it is similar to $A$.

Comment: Thanks to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to show that $A$ is similar to $e^A - I = A + \frac{A}{2!} + \cdots$. We show a more general statement that $A$ is similar to $B = A + a_2A^2 + a_3A^3 + \cdots$ for arbitrary coefficients $a_2, a_3, \cdots$.

It's enough to show this when $A$ has a single Jordan block, i.e. there is a vector $v_0$ such that $\{ v_0, v_1=Av_0, v_2=Av_1, \cdots \}$ form a basis of $\mathbb C^n$. Now it's enough to show that $v_0, Bv_0, B^2v_0, B^3 v_0$ are linearly independent. Note that the coefficients of $v_i$ in $B^jv_0$ is $\delta_{ij}$ for $i\le j$. The matrix of $v_0, Bv_0, \cdots$ under the basis $v_0, v_1, \cdots$ is triangular with only $1$ on the diagonal, hence they are linearly independent.

Comment: In addition to showing that $v_0,Bv_0,\dots,B^{n-1}v_0$ are linearly independent, it is necessary to note/show that $B$ is also nilpotent.

Comment: I don't see why it's necessary, but if you want, that would follow directly from the linear independence, as the matrix of $B$ can be written down directly.

Comment: The fact that $v_0, Bv_0, \dots, B^{n-1}v_0$ merely shows that $B$ has a [cyclic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace). This gives us no reason to believe, for instance, that $B$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm implicitly using $B (B^{n-1} v_0) = 0$ instead of a non-trivial linear combintion of $v_0, Bv_0, \cdots$, so the eigenvalue condition is implicitly contained.

Comment: Right, I think that for pedagogical purposes, that usage should be made explicit.

Comment: Thanks to answer.